# Double for loop within a while loop, can't find out what's wrong

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

[From Editor: Please expand this post further, explain what you were trying to do. the community can't easily figure out how we can help you if we don't know what you were attempting.]

I find out many of examples but still not understand what I wrong! 
Also, please state the reason or the way to use, which could help me to master other similar programs.

```
package twinprimes9;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwinPrimes9 {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=0,y=0,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,i=0,j=0;
    int count;
    int rg = 0;
    int rd = 1;
    int p;
    int fg;
    while (rg!=-1){
        System.out.println("Round "+rd);
        System.out.println("Enter the search range (enter -1 to stop the procedure :) ");
        rg = sc.nextInt();
        fg=0;
        p=0;
        count=0;
        if (rg==-1){
            System.out.println("End");
        } // if0 end 
        else if (rg<-1){
            System.out.println("Invaild input, please enter again !" );
        } // else if (if0) end 
        else {

            for (i=3;i<rg;i++){

                for (j=2;j<i;j++){
                    if (i%j==0){
                       p=1;

                    } // if1 end
                } // for j loop end
                if (count==0&&p!=1){
                    a=i;
                    count++;
                }// else if1(if2) end 
                else if (count==1&&p!=1){
                    b=i;

               if ((b-a==2)&&fg==0){
                   System.out.println("("+a+","+b+")");
                   fg=1;
               } // if 4 ( if3 (if2)) end
               else if (b-a==2&&fg==1){
                   System.out.print("("+a+","+b+")");
                   fg=0;
               } // else if 4 (if3 (if2)) end

               }// else if3 (if2) end


            } // for i loop end 

        } // else (if0) end 
            rd++;
    } // while loop end 
}
}
```

Please help me out if you wish.

Comment: Why the C# tag? As for what's wrong, how can anyone say without knowing what *right* should look like? Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Oh, that tag was my bad, there wasn't a language tag first and I thought it looks like C# on the first glance, glad that you've corrected that now.